# Self Adjoint operator $\Rightarrow$ Idempotent Operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, idempotents

If $P\in\mathcal{L}(H,H)$, with $H$ a Hilbert space, such that $P = P^*$, Is possible to show that $P^2 = P$?

If that is possible, then $P$ is a projection operator, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $H=\mathbb{R}^n$, usual inner product, $P:x\mapsto 2x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An operator $P$ satisfying $P = P^{\ast}$ is called *self-adjoint*. There are plenty of self-adjoint operators that do not satisfy $P^2 = P$; for example, $P = 2I$, as proximal mentioned.

An operator $P$ satisfying $P = P^2$ is called a *projection*. Not all projections are self-adjoint, such as $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

An operator that satisfies both is called an orthogonal projection.

Comment: Actually, in Operator Algebras, the former are called idempotents, the latter simply projections (=self-adjoint idempotents). And these words get used a lot in this field (von Neumann algebras, $C^*$-algebras...).